# htaccess redirecting to xml file instead of php

Tags: .htaccess, sitemap

I have the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This changes all my queries such as mysite.com/index.php?s=example to mysite.com/example. Thats okay there. The problem comes with my sitemap page. When you enter this address mysite.com/sitemap instead of redirecting you to mysite.com/index.php?s=sitemap it displays my sitemap.xml file which is located at my directory root.

How can I stop this from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `/sitemap` a directory also?

Comment: No, its not but there is a page called mysite.com/index.php?s=sitemap

Comment: Yes I know `/sitemap` should be rewritten to `/index.php?s=sitemap` but last rule is already doing that unless you have a directory or file named `/sitemap`

Comment: The only file named sitemap is sitemap.xml and if i rename it to sitemap2.xml or so then my page displays alright but i cant change that because its important to have it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to disable `MultiViews` here. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/sitemap` can be in URL but it will serve `/sitemap.xml`.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now I am getting a 500 error.

Comment: Probably `Options` isn't allowed in your .htaccess by Apache config. You need to enable by using ``Options All` there. Also check your Apache error.log file for reason of 500 error

Comment: Its a shared server and I dont have root access.

Comment: Any alternative please?

Comment: That doesn't require root access. Setting Options is enabled for me on a shared hosting. You just need to talk to your server admins.

Comment: I did so but they told me they cant because of security reasons. Isnt there any other alternative for me?

Comment: No there is nothing we can do since mod_rewrite runs after content negotiation module which in itself is a security risk if enabled. Your server admins need to be educated.